# Shear Stress at Boundaries of two Infinite Parallel Plates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow, stress-strain, viscosity

This is a worked example on a book I am reading (Fundamentals of fluid Mechanics).

They calculate the shearing stress in the top layer, bottom layer and middle layer.

The calculate  > 0 (in the fluid direction, they explain) for bottom layer, =0 for middle layer and  < 0 for top layer.

I do not understand how the shear can go be in opposite directions, especially given the symmetry of the problem, and the velocity acting in the same magnitude and direction at both plates.

Hope you can help me out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is a "leading" question:  In what direction is the shear force exerted by the fluid on the top wall?  In what direction is the shear force exerted by the fluid on the bottom wall?

Comment: The author described the positive shear calculated at the bottom to be in the direction of flow. But, that would imply that at the top the shear is in the opposite direction, as it is negative. From the symmetry of the problem i would conclude it is not possible for the shear on top to be going at a different direction, it should be going in the same direction as the one on the bottom. Or very possible there is just an inconsistency as to how i'm trying to understand the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since the stress tensor is a 2nd order tensor, it has a bidirectional nature.  So, at a given plane, the components are both positive and negative depending on what we say is acting on what, and the directions we are referring to.  Are you familiar with dyadic tensor notation?  Are you familiar with the Cauchy stress relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this flow and geometry, the $\tau_{xy}$ shear stress component of the stress tensor, is the stress on a plane of constant y in the x-direction **exerted by the material at $y^+$ on the material at $y^-$**.

At the interface at the bottom wall, the material at $y^+$ is the fluid and the material at $y^-$ is the wall.  So this is the shear stress exerted by the fluid on the bottom wall, and, from the diagram, it is in the +x-direction, so it is positive.  The shear stress exerted by the wall on the fluid, by Newton's 3rd law, is in the opposite direction.

At the fluid interface at the top wall, the material at $y^+$ is the wall and the material at $y^-$ is the fluid.  So this is the shear stress exerted by the wall on the fluid, and, from the diagram, it is in the negative x-direction, so it is negative.  The shear stress exerted by the fluid on the wall, by Newton's 3rd law is in the opposite direction.

All this sounds very complicated, but it follows directly from the so-called Cauchy Stress relationship.

Comment: I agree with your explanation, the author; however, does not explain it like that, and he states: at the bottom f(-h) = Txy > 0 ( wall experiences shear in direction +x) , and at the top f(h) = Txy < 0 , this indicates that the flow is in the opposite direction. That's where I get confused.

Comment: I guess he should have been more precise on how he expressed himself.

Comment: The same equation says shear at the top is negative, does that sign has anything to do with the direction of the shear? I want to visualize those position.

Comment: The shear stress at the top exerted by the wall on the fluid is in the negative x direction, and the shear stress at the top exerted by the fluid on the wall is in the positive x direction.

Comment: The book used the same formula to calculate the stress on the pipe for both bottom and top. Where, f(-h) = positive shear, where we agree. But it says the stress at the top wall exerted by the fluid is negative. Thus it would be pointing in the -x direction.

Comment: Well, that’s incorrect.  Your own eyes can see that.

Comment: Yes I can see that it makes no sense, but that is why I was wondering if it was incorrect or I was interpreting wrong. I have further improved the question including a graph of Tau vs y.

Comment: The graph shows the shear stress exerted by the material at $y^+$ on the material at $y^-$.  At y=h, that would be the shear stress exerted by the wall on the fluid.  The Cauchy Stress Relationship formalizes how to infallibly arrive at the correct result mathematically.

Comment: I do not understand why at y=-h is the shear stress by fluid on wall, but at y=h is the stress by wall on fluid. Thank you so much for taking the time by the way.

Comment: What's shown on the graph is the shear stress exerted by the material (fluid or pipe wall) at $y^+$ on the material (fluid or pipe wall) at $y^-$.  At y = -h, the material at $y^+$ is fluid and the material at $y^-$ is pipe wall.  At y = +h, the  the material at $y^+$ is pipe wall and the material at $y^-$ is fluid.  At y locations between -h and +h, $y^+$ represents the fluid above location y, and $y^-$ represents the fluid below location y.  So, at all locations above y = 0, the fluid above location y is exerting a shear stress in the -x direction on the fluid below location y.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118314/discussion-between-chet-miller-and-rsm).

Comment: What is the Cauchy Stress Relationship? I only see results for the tensor when I Google that term.

Comment: The Cauchy Stress Relationship is an equation which enables you to employ the stress tensor to determine the stress vector (aka traction vector) on an arbitrarily oriented element of area either interior to a body (or fluid) or at its exterior surface.  To do this, one focuses on a unit vector n oriented normal to the arbitrary area element.  According to the CSR, the traction vector acting on the element of area is equal to the stress tensor contracted (i.e., dotted) with the unit normal.